# Why Seting the SetMode to orbit disables custom KeyPressFcn event handlers, the callback

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

1-The code below displays the properties of the pressed key.Try it by pressing a key and observe the results.

```
figure('Name','Press keys to put event data in Command Window',...
         'KeyPressFcn',@(obj,evt)disp(evt));
```

you will see outputs like this( e.g upon pressing space bar)

```
    Character: ' '
     Modifier: {1x0 cell}
          Key: 'space'
```

2-Now simply add the following line of code to above ( or simply execute it before clearing the workspace)

```
    cameratoolbar('SetMode','orbit');
```

Now press any key and nothing happens! the control will no longer be transferred to your costume call back function! ( here:@(obj,evt)disp(evt)).

same thing happens  for WindowButtonDownFcn, WindowButtonUpFcn too.

**How** can I get around this? I wanna be able to handle KeyPressFcn or WindowButtonDownFcn after executing cameratoolbar('SetMode','orbit').

Comment: Does `cameratoolbar('SetMode','orbit');` work by itself (without being in the callback)?

Comment: Yes, but The problem is not cameratoolbar('SetMode','orbit'), it is the KeyPressFcn which does not work after calling cameratoolbar('SetMode','orbit')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: Once the cameratoolbar('SetMode','orbit') is called one of these two happens:the handle to the figure is lost or the event handler gets its default value. I am not sure which one though. Therefore we can **add the following code** to re-assign the lost handler back to our own call back function:

```
set(gcf,'KeyPressFcn',@(obj,evt)disp(evt))
```

Comment: Well found! It's bad design really.